# gooseberry "turnover" filling very thick

Tags: thickening, texture, stuffing

We got a lot of gooseberries from the garden, so I decided to make some gooseberry turnovers.
I found a simple recipe online: puree the berries, add bread-crumbs, cornstarch and sugar. Mix it, and fill some puff pastry. In the over, done!

But, the filling is so thick! I know gooseberries contain a certain amount of pectin, but even after removing the cornstarch and reduce the amount of bread-crumbs, it still ends up as a very thick, "solidified" substance.
Another problem is that the stuffing is quite liquid, which makes it difficult to fill the puff pastry. (that's why the bread-crumbs are added)

What can I do to thicken the stuffing, but prevent the filling from becoming solid?

Comment: wait, what is "the filling" and what is "the stuffing"? I assume that they are two different things, as one is too thick and the other is too liquid, but in your recipe, it looks like there is only one mix you fill into the puff pastry? Also, possible duplicate of http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24259/how-to-prevent-pureed-blueberries-from-gelling, because I assume that the thickening in both cases is done by pectin.

Comment: I thought the OP means the same thing with it. It's too thick when done; but too liquid before it hits the oven.

Comment: @Mien is right. Sorry for the indistinctness. However, the other question does handle with the thickness, but not so much about the 'liquidness' it is before...

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any resources on what to do when you have food with too much pectin in it, but you could combine the goose berries with something which has a low amount of pectin, [check out group II or III in this pdf](http://www.portlandpreserve.com/All%20About%20Pectin%20for%20Jam%20Makers.PDF). Don't puree your other ingredient totally and you'll get a thicker filling, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Put the gooseberries (raw) on the puff pastry rounds with a tsp sugar crimp pastry, cook in oven for 15 mins. til golden.
Simple.